# UPDATE query involving the results of 2 seperate SELECT statements from same table

Tags: mysql

currently i'm having an issue with UPDATE statements in SQL.
My scenario being when employee with id `114` leaves, his/her supervisor would take over supervising that employee's personnel. Following the departure, the ID of that supervisor would be updated on all the employees affected by the change in supervisors.
(take note that this is all within a table "EMPLOYEE" with `supervisor_id` not compulsory for all employees)

```
SELECT employee_id
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE supervisor_id = (SELECT supervisor_id
                       FROM EMPLOYEE
                       WHERE employee_id = '114')
```

Wondering if i'm on the right track with the above, and how would one go about updating the change in `supervisor_id` using an UPDATE statement.
Thank you for taking time reading this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you could update your Table by:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET supervisor_id=(SELECT supervisor_id FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE employee_id = '114') WHERE employee_id=(SELECT employee_id FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE supervisor_id = (SELECT supervisor_id FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE employee_id = '114') )
```

Maybe this helps